# How do I destructure a tuple so that the bindings are mutable?

Tags: rust

If I have the following struct:

```
struct MyStruct { tuple: (i32, i32) };
```

And the following function:

```
// This will not compile
fn function(&mut struct: MyStruct) {
    let (val1, val2) = struct.tuple;
    val1 = 1;
    val2 = 2;
}
```

How do I borrow val1 and val2 as mutable so when I reassign them the changes appear in the original struct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've got a few problems:

- You've put the `&mut` in the wrong place; `&mut` is part of the type, not the argument (unless you're destructuring the argument, which you aren't).
- You can't call the argument `struct`, because that's a keyword.
- You can't assign to a mutable reference with straight assignment.

So, with those in mind, here's a working solution:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    tuple: (i32, i32),
}

fn function(s: &mut MyStruct) {
    let (ref mut val1, ref mut val2) = s.tuple;
    *val1 = 1;
    *val2 = 2;
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct { tuple: (0, 0) };
    function(&mut s);
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

The key here is that `ref` in a pattern binds by-reference; combining that with `mut` gives you a mutable reference.  Specifically, it gives you a pair of `&mut i32`s.  Since these are references, you have to de-reference them in order to assign through them (otherwise, you'd be trying to re-assign the reference itself).

Answer (score 9):

You have two slightly different questions.

You can create a mutable bind by saying `mut` twice:

```
fn main() {
    let a = (1, 2);
    let (mut b, mut c) = a;
    b += 1;
    c += 2;

    println!("{}, {}", b, c);
}
```

But to have it change in the original tuple, you need a *mutable reference* into that tuple:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = (1, 2);

    {
        let (ref mut b, ref mut c) = a;
        *b += 1;
        *c += 2;
        // Let mutable borrows end
    }

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a mutable reference to `MyStruct` `s` and dereference each tuple member:

```
// This *will* compile
fn function(s: &mut MyStruct) {
    let (val1, val2) = &mut s.tuple;
    *val1 = 1;
    *val2 = 2;
}
```