# How do I create a Rust iterator for multiple vectors that returns the next item as a tuple?

Tags: rust

I am doing an entity-component system. My data has vectors of components and a vector of entities. An entity has handles to the various components and components have a handle to their entity.

```
let entities: Vec<Entity> = Vec::new();
let positions: Vec<PositionComponent> = Vec::new();
let sprites: Vec<SpriteComponent> = Vec::new();
```

I would like to iterate over sprites and get the positions via the entity. Here is how I am doing that now:

```
for sprite in &sprites {
    // get entity from the sprite's entity_handle
    let entity = &entities[sprite.entity_handle];
    // get position from the entity's position handle
    let position = &positions[entity.position_handle];
}
```

Having looked at [amethyst/specs](https://github.com/amethyst/specs), I see they get a really pretty iterator syntax, and I am wondering how to achieve that for my own use. Here is an example of one of their iterators:

```
impl<'a> System<'a> for SysA {
    // These are the resources required for execution.
    // You can also define a struct and `#[derive(SystemData)]`,
    // see the `full` example.
    type SystemData = (WriteStorage<'a, Pos>, ReadStorage<'a, Vel>);

    fn run(&mut self, (mut pos, vel): Self::SystemData) {
        // The `.join()` combines multiple component storages,
        // so we get access to all entities which have
        // both a position and a velocity.
        for (pos, vel) in (&mut pos, &vel).join() {
            pos.0 += vel.0;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to have an iterator that returns a tuple of sprite and position, similar to the specs example above.

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. I've removed your unrelated question, which is likely answered by [How do I destructure a tuple so that the bindings are mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31595087/155423)

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like you want [`Iterator::zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip)

Comment: Something like this? `for (sprite, position) in sprites.iter().map (|s| (s, positions[entities[s.entity_handle].position_handle]))`

Comment: I think that will work Jmb, thanks. I'll give it a try but it seems like that is what I am looking for.